# Show that if M, N are non-zero commutative rings, then M×N always has zero divisors, and is not an integral domain or a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

Show that if M, N are non-zero commutative rings,

then M×N always has zero divisors, and is not an integral domain or a field.

How do I do this?!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the product of $(m,0)$ and $(0,n)$?

Comment: (m,0) (m,n) (0,0) (0,n) ?

Comment: I'm assuming your operations are componentwise. This would mean that $(m,n)(m',n') = (mm',nn')$. Do you see how this helps you?

Comment: Please don't judge me for not understanding this...

Comment: No judgement at all! You know how rings work, I'm sure. Do you understand what I wrote in my above comment?